# Presenting different partial views iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am working on an App where the screen is divided in to 4 sections a top bar with company logo etc, a content section, a bottom bar with some buttons in it and then add banner at the bottom.

The first run will request the user answers a series of questions. These will be presented in the content section. When each question is complete the user taps the next button in the bottom bar and the next question will scroll in right to left.

My question is what is the best way to achieve this? I had considered using a series of UIViews and animating them, but as there will be 20 or 30 questions (all different types, some with text answers, so with multi choice, some with dates) It would become quite hard to manage this in the storyboard.

Should I be using a view controller for each question? If so how can I only display the content section so that when it scrolls in the top and bottom sections of the initial view controller are still visible and their buttons etc... still active?

Is there a best practice way of achieving this?

Comment: Why not using UICollectionView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. View structure :

You can have a **[container view](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/21/ios-container-views/)** for the content section in which you can embed the view controller hierarchy which will show the question answers. 
However, you want to control the question flow from this view controller as the toolbar (bottom bar) contains controls which dictate the flow (next button).
So, add an identifier for the embed segue from the container view and in 'prepreForSegue' method, get control of the embedded view controller.

2. Navigation :

*Option 1:* You can embed a **[UIPageViewController](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)** within the container view and set show all question screens as pages of the page view controller.

*Option 2:* You can embed a **UINavigationController** and push the question screens into the navigation stack.

2. Question answer screen:

*Option 1:* You can create a **UITableViewController** and create one custom cell for each type of question and each type of answer. You can have 2 sections in the table view. Section 1 will have question cell(s) and the second section will have answer cells. This allows you to have any type of combination of question and answer UI. You can have a question with text and image by creating a TextView cell and an Image cell for question. Similarly you can have a single row in answers section for textual answers where as have all the options in a multiple choice question as separate rows with the 'checkmark' accessory for selected answer.

*Option 2:* You can create one separate view controller for each type of question. Depending on the question, create the relevant view controller and pass add i to the view hierarchy (depending on the chosen navigation option).

In any case, you will have to make sure that the data structure you design must be very strong and you view navigation is customizable and driven by the question answer data source.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks!